# Sorting Network SWAPs for 64 elements

Tags: c, sorting, swap, sorting-network

I am trying to use [Sorting Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) in a C program to sort a small list `A` of `n` elements. A Sorting Network consists of `SWAP(x, y)` macros, each of which compares two elements `A[x]` and `A[y]`, and swaps if necessary. This [website](http://pages.ripco.net/~jgamble/nw.html) generates the sequence of `SWAP(x, y)` macros for sorting `n <= 32` elements.

Now, I am looking for the `SWAP(x, y)` sequence for sorting `n = 64` elements. At this point, I am not sure if Sorting Network would be faster than using other sorting algorithms for `n = 64` elements, but I wish to test it. My question is: is there any website/paper/project that lists this sequence? Or is there any algorithm to generate for `n = 64` from the Sorting Networks for `n <= 32`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to shifting a circular array (Approach #3 in https://leetcode.com/articles/rotate-array/# )

There are algorithms to determine the sequence i.e. *Bose-Nelson algorithm* (https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Networksort), a C implementation is in https://github.com/atinm/bose-nelson/blob/master/bose-nelson.c

Comment: Bose-Nelson Sorting Network generator serves my purpose. However, I later found out that the [example-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batcher_odd%E2%80%93even_mergesort#Example_code) in the Batcher odd-even mergesort wiki also generates the `SWAP(x, y)` sequences I was looking for. Batcher's network has a lower number of `SWAP(x, y)` than the Bose-Nelson network (at least for `n=64`, `543` vs `665`).

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is interested (I was) in the question of how appropriate a sorting network is for 64 element sequences of 32 bit integers, I've just had a look myself and found the following:

- qsort took about 2600ns per sequence
- std::sort took about 1100 ns per sequence
- a Bose-Nelson Sorting Network took about 1200 ns per sequence
- a Batcher odd-even network took about 850ns per sequence
- a Batcher odd-even network working on 8 sequences concurrently using AVX2 instructions took 70ns per sequence

The sequences were uniformly generated, so maximum entropy, i.e. worst case, favouring a sorting network.

You might expect a theoretical 8x speedup using AVX2, why is there a 12x speedup?  Looking at the assembly, Clang performs multiple swaps of the sorting network in blocks like:

```
00007FF6DA081374  vpminsd     ymm4,ymm0,ymm1  
00007FF6DA081379  vpmaxsd     ymm0,ymm0,ymm1  
00007FF6DA08137E  vpminsd     ymm1,ymm2,ymm3  
00007FF6DA081383  vpmaxsd     ymm2,ymm2,ymm3  
00007FF6DA081388  vpminsd     ymm3,ymm4,ymm1  
00007FF6DA08138D  vpmaxsd     ymm1,ymm4,ymm1  
00007FF6DA081392  vpminsd     ymm4,ymm0,ymm2  
00007FF6DA081397  vpmaxsd     ymm0,ymm0,ymm2  
00007FF6DA08139C  vpminsd     ymm2,ymm4,ymm1  
00007FF6DA0813A1  vpmaxsd     ymm1,ymm4,ymm1
```

whereas the scalar code uses cmp, cmovgt, cmovlt instructions intermingled with mov's too and from memory.  Make of that what you will.

I used my own implementation and benchmarking code for the Batcher odd/even network available at https://github.com/jamesthomasgriffin/sorting_networks and, for the Bose-Nelson network, https://github.com/Vectorized/Static-Sort.

Answer (score 1):

The method that gives the best results for 64 inputs is probably the one described by David C. Van Voorhis. See link below for a similar network:

https://bertdobbelaere.github.io/sorting_networks_extended.html#N64L521D22